# How to use more than one library in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to open putty using robotframework that I had done with autoitlibrary but I want to give command as "ls -ltr" and capture it's output and compare with expected results using process library.

So can I use both library in single test case ? Means open putty using Autoitlibrary and execute my given command in putty using process library.

Comment: Interacting with putty is not real adviced (at least by me) -- better approach would be to use http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html which would bypass using autoitlibrary completely ..

Comment: You can use as many libraries as you want. It's not clear what you're asking. Have you tried importing more than one library to see what happens?